# Take(parameter) when collection count is less than parameter

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a list of objects TheListOfObjects.

If I write this:

```
TheListOfObjects = TheListOfObjects.Take(40).ToList();
```

Will it crash if there are only 30 items in the list or will it just return the first 30? And when TheListOfObjects  is empty, or even null?

Thanks.

Comment: this should be a really easy thing to test.  `var foo = (new[] {1,2}).Take(10);`

Comment: LinqPad is your friend in these cases...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is one of those where you *should* just try it or at least check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

> Will it crash if there are only 30 items in the list or will it just return the first 30?

It will just return the first 30.

> And when TheListOfObjects is empty

It will return the empty sequence.

> or even null?

It will result in a `ArgumentNullException`.

From MSDN:

> `Take<TSource>` enumerates source and yields elements until count elements have been yielded or source contains no more elements.
>
> If `count` is less than or equal to zero, `source` is not enumerated and an empty `IEnumerable<TSource>` is returned.

And under exceptions:

```
Exception             Condition
ArgumentNullException source is null
```

In the time it took you to log on to StackOverflow, you could have either checked MSDN and got an **authoritative** answer (notice that some mildly incorrect or partially incomplete answers have already been posted and deleted here) or fired up Visual Studio and greased your wheels a little bit.

Comment: So you say, but documentation sometimes misses this information so it feels like a waste of time to try documentation when I can google it on StackOverflow and find an answer. This answer helped me and I think this question is useful.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN says:

> Take(Of TSource) enumerates source and yields elements until count elements have been yielded or source contains no more elements.

Answer (score 3):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

> `Take<T>`  enumerates source and yields elements until count
>   elements have been yielded or source contains no more elements.
>
> If count is less than or equal to zero, source is not enumerated and
>   an empty `IEnumerable<T>` is returned.

Comment: +1 for posting the interesting second sentence -- I am rushing off now to create a collection type with a `Count` property that returns a negative value!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
TheListOfObjects = TheListOfObjects.Take(TheListOfObjects.Count > 30 ? 30 : TheListOfObjects.Count).ToList();
```